# datediff with conditions in select statment

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sql Server 2008
Datediff with conditions in the select statement.

I have the below query and need help understanding why I'm getting these results and best solution for my problem.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT l.program, l.id
     ,(DATEDIFF(DAY, B.FIRST_DT , B.FIRST_second_DT))days_between1
     ,(DATEDIFF(DAY, C.FIRST_DT , C.FIRST_second_DT))days_between2      
FROM  l
LEFT JOIN l B ON L.id = B.id AND L.SERVICE_DATE = B.SERVICE_DATE
              AND B.FIRST_DT IS NOT NULL AND B.FIRST_DT IS NOT NULL
              AND l.IS ='0' AND L.FIRST_V_DT IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN l C ON L.id = C.id AND L.SERVICE_DATE = C.SERVICE_DATE
              AND C.FIRST_DT IS NOT NULL
              AND C.FIRST_A_DT IS NOT NULL AND L.IS ='1'
              AND L.FIRST_DT IS NOT NULL
WHERE 1=1
```

I'm getting two lines

```
Program    id    daysbetween1      daysbetween2
blue        1        null              3
blue        1         4               null
```

How do I get one line, like below and why am I getting two lines?

```
Program    id    daysbetween1      daysbetween2
blue        1        4                3
```

Comment: Sample data would help here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Of course you get different rows, either L.IS ='0' or L.IS ='1'...

Comment: IS HAS TO DO WITH MY L.IS = 0 AND L.IS = 1 AND MY INNER JOINS. I'll work on sample data.

Comment: Right, I figured that out about 2 minuts ago :) What's the best approach around this, I was thinking about using temp tables?

Comment: @MrJohn take a look at my answer. See if it work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
SELECT l.program, l.id
     ,MAX((DATEDIFF(DAY, B.FIRST_DT , B.FIRST_second_DT))) days_between1
     ,MAX((DATEDIFF(DAY, C.FIRST_DT , C.FIRST_second_DT))) days_between2      
FROM  l
LEFT JOIN l B ON L.id = B.id AND L.SERVICE_DATE = B.SERVICE_DATE
              AND B.FIRST_DT IS NOT NULL AND B.FIRST_DT IS NOT NULL
              AND l.IS ='0' AND L.FIRST_V_DT IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN l C ON L.id = C.id AND L.SERVICE_DATE = C.SERVICE_DATE
              AND C.FIRST_DT IS NOT NULL
              AND C.FIRST_A_DT IS NOT NULL AND L.IS ='1'
              AND L.FIRST_DT IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY l.program, l.id
```

That `where` condition is unnecessary unless you are getting this SQL from some sort of dynamic concatenation of the filters.